# Can't install ElementaryOS!

Tags: system-installation

[image: My laptop has geforce g810m and my file system is gpt, UEFI 64bit]I used rufus to create my usb drive and i can't figure out why elementaryos doesn't want to install!

Comment: Have you tried to create your usb drive again? Perhaps the image was not copied correctly by Rufus.

Comment: Also, did you format the drive first? Format it through Rufus before you create the boot drive.

Comment: So installed other OS instead. I tried to use Rufus, Deepin boot maker, Unetbootin multiple times and it didn't work. It only was working when another linux os was installed, because it was searhing for missing items on HDD. Elementary OS is not for me anyway! I am very happy now using Antergos OS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and anyway I didn't really like Elementary OS, so I installed Antergos OS!!! 1000% better. It is just my opinion, don't take it close to heart!

Comment: I had some problems with rufus or any other usb image creation tools. If you don't want to use dd, unetbootin works always well for me. Your answer is funny, because you couldn't even install elementary os (because image creation tool sucks). But you know that Antergos it's 1000% better.